# How to use Encoder-Decoder RNN when my input and output are not length-fixed?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

For example,my every input data's length can be 5 or 10 or 15 ,it is not fixed, it is same as the output,how to handle this problem when I use Encoder-Decoder RNN (seq2seq)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the problem arises when mini-batching, otherwise, there is no problem processing each sample on its own..

The simplest strategy is to ensure all samples in a mini-batch have the same length.
Otherwise, another solution is padding, which adds a new symbol to the vocabulary called PAD, and then pads short samples to the length of the longest sample in the mini-batch.